# reload android layouts dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have android application with multi layouts, and there is change language layout, when the user change the language all the layouts should be changed, the problem is how to reload all the opened layout in the background of the application, maybe it is one layout or 2 or 3 that is depend on the user what he did before, I have some code that reload the last layout only but the others still in the last language

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                           .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
               i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               startActivity(i);
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

and when the layout reload its check the saved language form the SharedPreferences like this

```
  shared = getSharedPreferences(language.SavedLanguage, 0);
```

Is there any better idea to change the languages ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use spinner at right corner of the screen directly change the language accordingly the spinner item selected

Comment: thank you @Sridhar its look like great idea and I am working on it